# How To Query Databases in Subject-Predicate Format?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-theory, csv

I have csv data in this format:

```
id   fieldname fieldvalue
--   --------- ----------
1    fieldA    A1
1    fieldB    B1
2    fieldA    A2
2    fieldA    B2
```

If I upload this to MySQL, how can I convert the data easily to the conventional "relational format":

```
id   columnA   columnB
--   -------   -------
1    A1        B1
2    A2        B2
```

Otherwise how can I query data in this format? I’d like to be able to do things like `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE x=y OR a=b AND t=w`. Are there database software that specifically deal with this sort of data?

Lastly, is there a systematic name for such data representation? eg. we have "relational" data, XML data. I remember reading on the *.rdf* format standard and recall that it does resemble that, but I am not sure if there's a more general name.

Comment: What you are really asking is how to do a pivot/unpivot, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/7674786/447514

Comment: Your input data resembles the entity-attribute-value (EAV) model.